# Remove the signature from a MIME encoded email with PHP

Tags: php, email, pear, pop3, email-parsing

I am reading mails from a pop3 server with [imap](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) and decoding them with a mailparse class which uses PEAR [Mimedecode](http://codepad.org/LZNtORlT).

I was wondering if there's any way to get the signature or just to remove it from the body of the mail.

Thanks.

Comment: and php will be able to figure what's a signature and what's just some stuff in the email... how?

Comment: I'm asking because I don't know enough about how mail works. As well as it separates the sender, subject, body or attachments, i was wondering if it also separates the signature somehow. Maybe internally in the HTML body... That's why I ask :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature is part of the body, so no, there isn't really a way to just remove the signature, unless you knew that every signature was going to have the exact same format.

If you knew that every signature was going to come after 10 hyphens, like this

```
Lorem ipsum lorem ispum.Lorem ipsum lorem ispum.Lorem ipsum lorem ispum.
Lorem ipsum lorem ispum.Lorem ipsum lorem ispum.
----------
Your Name
```

If that is the case, then you could just do

```
$message = explode('----------', $body);
```

Where $message[0] would be the body, and $message[1] would be the signature.